# how to compare in std::string or char* with BOOST framework (using boost/test/unit_test.hpp)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

How to compare `std::string` or `char`* with liternal string using BOOST unit test framework (using `boost/test/unit_test.hpp`),

`BOOST_CHECK` and `BOOST_TEST` does not work with string.

Comment: `BOOST_CHECK(s1 == s2)` doesn't work?

Comment: `std::string` or `char*` ?? Did you mean compare `std::string` **with** `char*` ?

Comment: At the very least you should [edit] your question to include an [mcve]. If you're comparing two strings, what doesn't work, does it fail to compile, give a runtime error or not work as expected?

Comment: sorry, updated the question, tried below:                                                      
wchar_t wcstring[30];                                                                      
wcscpy(wcstring, L"犬 means dog");
BOOST_CHECK(std::wstring(wcstring) == L"犬 means dog");

Comment: @user1174114 Current Boost.Test 1.73 does not support wide strings or encoding. Consider making a feature request on the project's GitHub.